# XSLT Index of groups created by for-each-group

Tags: xslt, indexing, grouping

I need to divide a long table into smaller tables using for-each-group with the group-ending-with attribute. Inside each table I need to have the index of that group but I cannot find out which variable is available for that - if there is one.

Sample xml:

```
<table>
  <row type='A'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='A'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='A'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='A'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
</table>
```

Desired output:

```
<table>
  <title>Table 1</title>
  <row type='A'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
</table>
<table>
  <title>Table 2</title>
  <row type='A'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
</table>
<table>
  <title>Table 3</title>
  <row type='A'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
</table>
<table>
  <title>Table 4</title>
  <row type='A'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
  <row type='B'><cell>Some value</cell>
</table>
```

I have the grouping done, but I cannot find a way to get the index to put into the table titles. Maybe it is trivial but the search words group and index do not give any useful result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `position()` function.

*No code, since no code was provided - and neither the sample input nor the expected output are well-formed XML.*

(Addition by Michael Kay): Last para of §14.1 https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-for-each-group reads: -

> "The sequence constructor contained in the xsl:for-each-group element
>   is evaluated once for each of the groups, in processing order. The
>   sequences that result are concatenated, in processing order, to form
>   the result of the xsl:for-each-group element. Within the sequence
>   constructor, the context item is the initial item of the relevant
>   group, the context position is the position of this group in the
>   processing order of the groups, and the context size is the number of
>   groups. This has the effect that within the sequence constructor, a
>   call on position() takes successive values 1, 2, ... last()."

Comment: Is it that simple. I was thinking position() would point to the element in the original gorup, but of course it makes sense now. Thanks. Sorry about the sketchy XML - the actual XML is way too elaborate to be posting here.